# I have problem with dark mode and local storage! (using React & Tailwind)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, local-storage, tailwind-css

I make a toggle switch for dark and light mode and it work perfect, but the problem is with local storage it doesn't work!

```
const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isDark) {
    document.body.classList.remove('dark');
    localStorage.setItem(setIsDark, 'light')
    document.body.classList.add('light');
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('light');
      document.body.classList.add('dark');
      localStorage.setItem(setIsDark, 'dark')
    }
}, [isDark]); 


`for HTML code`


<label class="relative inline-flex items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">

`This is the input`
<input checked={isDark} onClick={({target}) => setIsDark(target.checked)} type="checkbox" value="" class="sr-only peer"/>

<div class="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer dark:bg-gray-700 peer-focus:ring-4 peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all dark:border-gray-600 peer-checked:bg-[#0a192f]"></div>
<span class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300"></span>
</label>
```

I have tried multiple way with the local storage and one work with me but all the solution it doesn't use the method that I use

here the CSS code

```
.dark {
    --background: #0a192f;
    --textmaincolor: #e5e7eb;
    --textcolor: #8892b0;
    --buttonbg: #db2777;
    --border-color: #fff;
    --nameTxt: #db2777;
    --logo: url('assets/PortfolioWhite.png');
    --skillsColor: #0a192f;
}


.light {
    --background: #e5e7eb;
    --textmaincolor: #0a192f;
    --textcolor: #3e4856;
    --buttonbg: #656565;
    --border-color: #000;
    --nameTxt: #0a192f;
    --logo: url('assets/PortfolioTrans.png');
    --skillsColor: #3e4856;
}
```

I didn't change my method because I build big project and it took me weeks and I just need to add dark mode :)

Comment: `localStorage.setItem(setIsDark, 'light')` doesn't look right. LS is a key/value system so the first argument should be the storage key not a reference to the state setter function. Maybe `localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')`, for example.

Comment: I have change it but it doesn't save in the local storage!